# Intervention Image. Get md5 hash

Tags: php, gd, intervention

I using intervention library. And want to get md5($image), **not** hash of image path.

I am doing `$interventionPicture = Image::make($pictureUrl)`  and get object.

Just saw someting like that: `md5(file_get_contents($file->path()))`.

But need to use Intervention way.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong about that. What is bad of using PHP native functions?

Comment: If you are using UploadedFile, there is a method called hashName()